# How to fix the card and set 3 cards on the same row?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, card

I want to use the Card to display the list of Projects. the issue is here every card is on a row, not as my expected 3 projects in a row and it does not display as a Card, it loses some borders between header, body, and footer. I want it displayed like below

[image]

However, it displayed like this

[image]

My code is here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CardDeck } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {
  Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
  CardTitle, CardLink, CardFooter
} from 'reactstrap';
class Portfolio extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.data) {
      var projects = this.props.data.projects.map(function (projects) {
        var projectImage = 'images/portfolio/' + projects.image;
        return (
          <CardDeck >
            <Card >
              <CardImg top width="40%" src={projectImage} alt="Card image cap" />
              <CardBody>
                <CardTitle style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>{projects.title}</CardTitle>
                <CardText>{projects.category}</CardText>
               
              </CardBody>
              <CardFooter>
                <small className="text-muted">Last updated {projects.time} ago</small>
              </CardFooter>
            </Card>
          </CardDeck>
        )
      })
    }

    return (
      <section id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center ">
                <div class="content">
        {/* <div className="twelve columns collapsed"> */}
                    <h1>PROJECTS</h1>
                  <div id="portfolio-wrapper" className="bgrid-quarters s-bgrid-thirds cf">
                    {projects}
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

Can someone stop by give me help? I am really appreciated that!

Comment: You've made a card deck with only one card. Why do you expect there are 3 cards when you literally only have 1 card defined in the deck.

Comment: Did you see I store everything in the json.file?

Comment: The card does not display as my expected, do you know why?

Comment: I think what I said is still valid. I have never used cards but to me this looks like you are opening a deck, adding the card and then closing the deck. When you add your second you make a brand new deck. Not open the old one. You would need to make a loop in the card deck instead of outside it. (I might be wrong but i've had this problem with different objects so it might apply here. But I'm not making this an offical answer because I'm not certain it is correct at all)